# Create plug-in like infrastructure for React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, import

I would like to create a React app that uses a plug-in like infrastructure. Meaning, in the app there is some basic functionality that is always available but it can be enhanced with plug-ins that can be enabled using a config file that is setting environment variables.

I have achieved the goal with dynamically importing components and Javascript functions but I have an issue with dynamically importing Typescript types that should only be used when the plugin is enabled. I have created an App example that shows the approach I'm taking (not sure if this is the best approach either). You can find the whole app here:
[My app on Stackblitz](https://react-ts-atha2j.stackblitz.io)

The App.tsx file is where it all comes together:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import CompA from './components/CompA';

function App() {
//  const ENV_VARS = window.__RUNTIME_CONFIG__;
//  let showPlugin1: boolean = ENV_VARS.ENABLED_PLUGINS.includes('PLUGIN_1');
  let showPlugin1 = true;

  let PluginB: any;
  let PluginC: any;
  let FuncA: any = undefined;
  const [FuncVal, setFuncVal] = React.useState<string | undefined>();
  let TypedFunction: any = undefined;

  if (showPlugin1) {
    PluginB = React.lazy(() => import('./components/plugins/CompB'));
    PluginC = React.lazy(() => import('./exports/CompC'));

    const loader = async () => {
      ({ FuncA } = await import('./components/plugins/Functions'));
      setFuncVal(FuncA());
    };
    loader();

    // import type {TypeA} from './components/plugins/Functions';

    // TypedFunction = (testType: TypeA) => {
    //   return <div>Function Call with TypeA</div>
    // }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CompA />
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading Plugins...</div>}>
        {PluginB && <PluginB />}
        {PluginC && <PluginC />}
        {FuncVal && FuncVal}
        {TypedFunction && TypedFunction()}
      </React.Suspense>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see I have commented out the part where I tried to import the type from a file depending on a setting of a variable. Also the part where I read the environment variable from the settings file is commented out because this does not seem to work on Stackblitz.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this question was kinda stupid. I solved the issue by moving my type definitions into a .d.ts file so I didn't have to export or import them anymore.

So my solution to have a plugin based structure like above works fine now. I'm not saying that this is the best solution but at least it works.